# Symfony 6 - Dynamic service loading

Tags: symfony, symfony6

Can I load services.yaml depending server env file, my code that does not work below :

```
// config\services.yaml
... some config
imports:
  - { resource: packages/dashboard/services_%env(CURRENT_APP)%.yaml }
```

Here is the .env file

```
... some env variables
# Current APP Toggle
CURRENT_APP='app'
```

and of course the dashboard services_app.yaml

```
parameters:
  # Here declare dashboard context parameters
  app.dashboard_enabled: false
services:
  # Here declare dashboard context specific services
```

I'm hoping to diverge usage of the same code to different applications but I get the error that the yaml does not exist

```
The file "services_%env(CURRENT_APP)%.yaml" does not exist
```

Comment: I am going to say no because env values are basically loaded upon each request.  Containers are built once and then cached.  Even if you got it to work your don't want to rebuild the container on each request just because an env variable was changed.

Comment: env variable will change from server to server it will not change frequently.
The idea is to have the same code base run on different servers but with two different behaviours

Comment: I even tried to make import dynamyc just by passing a parameter (not env) that does not work either : 
{ resource: "services_%current_app%.yaml" }

Comment: The official documentation explains that is not possible to use variables to build paths: "Due to the way in which parameters are resolved, you cannot use them to build paths in imports dynamically." (https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters)

Comment: If you only have a few server configs then you might be able to create a Symfony [configuration environment](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments) for each one.  So instead of 'prod' you might have 'prod1','prod2' etc.  Otherwise I think you just have to let the services be defined and then use CURRENT_APP to control their behavior.